# How do I forward routing to Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

We have an old website that has a custom ACL and routing setup. We are slowly migrating the code base to Laravel.

In order to get to a page from the old site, everything currently runs through a file called `Modules.php`, and the modname specifies which page should be opened. For example: `/Modules.php?modname=hello/world` displays the world page.

How could I fake the route for laravel? I want to start Laravel from the Modules.php and use the modname as the route.

So I should be able to do something like this: `Route::get('/hello/world', 'MyController@hello');`

Right now I am simply overwriting `$_SERVER`, but the problem with that is things like getting the base URL become a problem.

**If anyone would like to do this in the future, here's what we did:**

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$request->server->set('REQUEST_URI', $_REQUEST['modname']);
$app->run($request);
```

In laravel 5, you can do the equivalent by passing `$request` input the Kernel (use public/index.php as a reference)

As for how we determine if a route is a laravel route, I made this function. You could probably optimize it by making the json file a binary tree, but I didn't notice in performance problems, so I didn't bother.

```
<?php

/**
 * Checks if Laravel should handle the request.
 *
 * @param $route string The route used internally by Laravel. Ex: sss/events
 * @return boolean Whether Laravel creates the response for this route
 */
function IsLaravelRoute($route)
{
    // The json file is made by running `php artisan routes:dump` in Laravel
    // We compile the routes for performance by defering booting Laravel
    // only if we know for sure that it is needed
    $routeFilePath = realpath(__DIR__.'/../laravel.json');

    // If Laravel isn't installed on the site, it's obviously not a Laravel route
    if ($routeFilePath === false) {
        return false;
    }

    // An array of objects with details foreach Laravel route
    $laravelRoutes = json_decode(file_get_contents($routeFilePath));

    // Some info we'll need to verify the route adheres to a route pattern
    $requestMethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    $route         = trim($route, '/');
    $segments      = explode('/', $route);
    $len           = count($segments);

    foreach($laravelRoutes as $laravelRoute) {
        // Format the laravel route details in such a way we can compare
        // it with the route being checked
        $routeSegments      = explode('/', $laravelRoute->uri);
        $routeLen           = count($routeSegments);
        $optionalParamCount = preg_match_all('/(\{.*\?\})/', $laravelRoute->uri);

        // These conditions must be true; otherwise, we skip this iteration.
        $sameMethods      = in_array($requestMethod, $laravelRoute->methods);
        $sameSegmentCount = $len === $routeLen;

        // See if optional params can meet us half way
        $routeDiff = $routeLen - $len;

        // Possibly a route, we'll verify that
        // it is in fact one later if this is true
        $potentialRoute = $optionalParamCount >= $routeDiff && $routeDiff >= 0;

        $looksLegit = $sameMethods && ($sameSegmentCount || $potentialRoute);
        if (!$looksLegit) {
            continue; // Ain't nobody got time for that
        }

        // Basic requirements for elgibility is there -- now verify
        for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
            // We can only validate concrete route segments;
            // we have to give the benefit of the doubt to route parameters.
            $validate = !preg_match('/\{.*\}/', $routeSegments[$i]);
            if ($validate && $segments[$i] !== $routeSegments[$i]) {
                // This route isn't valid, but let's check the next $laravelRoute
                continue 2;
            }
        }

        // This route is legit
        return true;
    }

    // Looked through all the routes, but looks like it isn't a Laravel page :(
    return false;
}
```

And of course we wanted to used named routes, so Laravel would generate new routes, but in order to do that we extended UrlGenerator. Please forgive the global variable.

```
<?php namespace Focus\Core\Route;

/**
 * When the time comes just remove this class
 * and use the default Laravel UrlGenerator class
 */
class UrlGenerator extends \Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator
{
    /**
     * We build the URL that is needed. This will pass everything through
     * Modules.php
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Route  $route
     * @param  array  $parameters
     * @param  bool  $absolute
     * @return string
     */
    protected function toRoute($route, array $parameters, $absolute)
    {
        global $FocusURL;

        $modname = $this->replaceRouteParameters($route->uri(), $parameters);

        if (sizeof($parameters) > 0) {
            // Append query string onto existing
            $queryString = $this->getRouteQueryString($parameters);
            $queryString = '&'.substr($queryString, 1);
        } else {
            $queryString = '';
        }

        $url = '/Modules.php?modname='.$modname.$queryString;

        return $absolute ? rtrim($FocusURL, '/').$url : ltrim($url, '/');
    }

    /**
     * Generate a URL to an application asset.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @param  bool    $secure
     * @return string
     */
    public function asset($path, $secure = null)
    {
        global $FocusURL;

        if ($this->isValidUrl($path)) return $path;

        // Shortcut to access a package's assets
        if (strpos($path, '@') === 0) {
            $path = 'packages/focus/'.substr($path, 1);
        }

        $path = ltrim($path, '/');
        $filePath = base_path().'/public/'.$path;

        // Prevent loading old version of assets due to caching
        if (file_exists($filePath)) {
            $path .= '?'.filemtime($filePath);
        }

        return rtrim($FocusURL, '/').'/laravel/public/'.$path;
    }
}
```

As for how that laravel.json file got there for the IsLaravel function to check, we made this artisan command and we watch it with gulp for changes

```
<?php namespace Focus\Core\Command;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Routing\Route;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

class RouteDumper extends Command {

    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = 'routes:dump';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Creates a file that can be included in old focus to find laravel routes without starting the entire framework each request.';

    protected $router;
    protected $routes;

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->routes = $router->getRoutes();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function fire()
    {
        $json = array();
        foreach ($this->routes as $route) {
            $json[] = array(
                'methods' => $route->methods(),
                'uri' => $route->uri()
            );
        }

        $path = base_path().'/../laravel.json';
        $fileContents = json_encode($json);
        File::put($path, $fileContents);

        //$this->call("generate:laroute");

        $this->info('All routes have been dumped!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the console command arguments.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getArguments()
    {
        return array();
    }

    /**
     * Get the console command options.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        return array();
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use restful/controller routes if you want to simplify things...  I don't know if that is what you are asking though `Route::controller('hello','HelloController');` then you would just have an action in the controller: `getWorld()`

Comment: What does your .htacess file look like?  Laravel uses mod_rewrite to route requests through /index.php  Does your legacy code make use of mod_rewrite in the same way?

Comment: The legacy code doesn't use mod_rewrite, but I am using the .htaccess file that came with Laravel.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may create a request using `Request::create` method, something like this

```
// Get the url
$modname = "hello/world";

$request = Request::create($modname, 'GET', array());
return Route::dispatch($request);
```